# Hardware Reuirements

Tags: mysql

We are into healthcare domain.And planning to install MySQL.Please suggest me what are the basic requirements need from hardware.like memory,cpu etc.

Expecting data growth is 200GB per year.

Comment: Basic requirement:  big disk.  Other things (CPU, RAM, etc) depend on the application code.  ("healthcare domain" is much to broad for me to be more specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Memory and CPU has to do with your expected performance needs. DB size has negligible impact on actual DB performance, but it has to deal with anticipated average concurrent DB sessions and what specific queries you plan on encoding to the database.

It is recommended in my portion of the healthcare industry to never have less than 3 months growth worth of freespace in the system, and when we add more we add up to 9 months worth of growth. (In your case, when your system hits 50GB of free space, we would add 100GB)

If I recall correctly, MySQL has specific licencing for different node/CPU counts. I would use that as a guideline, to pick which licence makes sense for your business and to max out the CPU count for that licence level. As far as RAM, I would initially look at 64G to 128G range.

Take this with a grain of salt, as I mainly work in Oracle RDBMS. Please confirm with other resources before proceeding.

Comment: Mysql has no licence limitations for node,  cpus or memory. At least the community edition.